# applying categories at the class level

Tags: groovy

If I want to use a Groovy category within a short block of code, I usually do so like this

```
def foo() {

  use(TimeCategory) {
    new Date() + 5.hours
  }
}
```

However if I want to use a category in several methods of the same class, it's tedious to have to repeat the call to `use` in each method.

Is there a way to apply a category at the class-level? I tried using Groovy's `@Mixin` annotation like so:

```
import groovy.time.*

@Mixin(TimeCategory)
class Foo {

  Foo() {
    new Date() + 5.hours
  }
}

new Foo()
```

But if you execute the code above in the Groovy console you get an exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hour for class: java.lang.Integer

Comment: A `@WithCategory` AST would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MetaClass.invokeMethod()` after the fact. It's a bit ugly, but it keeps the class code relatively clean:

```
import groovy.time.*

class Foo {
  Foo() {
    try { println (new Date() + 5.hours) }
    catch (e) { println e }

    try { println afterHours(5) }
    catch (e) { println e }
  }

  Date tomorrow() {
    new Date() + 1.days
  }

  Date nextWeek() {
    new Date() + 7.days
  }

  Date afterHours(int h) {
    new Date() + h.hours
  }
}
```

Solution #1: Modified the `Foo.metaClass` somewhere downstream as follows:

```
Foo.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
  def metaMethod = Foo.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
  def result
  use(TimeCategory) {
    result = metaMethod.invoke(delegate.delegate, args)
  }
  return result
}
```

Testing it as follows:

```
def foo = new Foo()
println "tomorrow: ${foo.tomorrow()}"
println "next week: ${foo.nextWeek()}"
println "after 7 hours: ${foo.afterHours(7)} "
```

Yields the following results

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hours for class: java.lang.Integer
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: hours for class: java.lang.Integer
tomorrow: Fri Oct 17 14:46:52 CDT 2014
next week: Thu Oct 23 14:46:52 CDT 2014
after 7 hours: Thu Oct 16 21:46:52 CDT 2014
```

So it doesn't work in or through constructors, but it works everywhere else.

---

If you don't mind changing the behavior of Integer and Date globally, then you could use the following solution instead.

Solution #2:

With the same class as before, instead of modifying `Foo.metaClass`, modify `Integer.metaclass` and `Date.metaClass` as follows:

```
Integer.metaClass.mixin TimeCategory
Date.metaClass.mixin TimeCategory
```

Now the same test as before yields the following output:

```
Thu Oct 16 21:19:24 CDT 2014
Thu Oct 16 21:19:24 CDT 2014
tomorrow: Fri Oct 17 16:19:24 CDT 2014
next week: Thu Oct 23 16:19:24 CDT 2014
after 7 hours: Thu Oct 16 23:19:24 CDT 2014
```

Comment: Solution #2 will make `TImeCategory` available globally, but what I'm looking for is a way to scope them to a single class

Comment: @Dónal, understood. I thought that might be the case.